# show images equal view opportunity

Tags: image, view

I am looking for a solution for a shopping cart (php and mysql) where on front home page 20 product images are loaded randomly. I would like to know is there a better way to manage and give equal opportunity to load product images not loaded before so each product/content gets equal chance to appear instead of random as random might pick previously view again.

I was thinking to add views table in the database so each product views are stored so when product are picked randomly check the views if any product has greater view drop that and select more randomly .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make a distinct select from your Products table so that there will be no duplicate images:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, ProductImage FROM ProductsTables
```